# Provider for custom annotation

Tags: java, guice, provider

How with Google Guice create provider for custom annotations.

@SuperAnno Object test - my custom annotation

If this annotation find, system automatically call provider for convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Guice module:

```
@Provides
@SuperAnno
Object get() {
    return MyObject.getInstance(); // for example
}
```

In your main class:

```
@Inject
@SuperAnno
Object injectedObject;

public doStuff() {
    // do stuff with injected field
}
```

I would recommend using a more specific type than `Object`.  Your question is not entirely clear to me so I used Object since it seems like you wanted to.  Please explain question further if this does not answer it.